# Querying flask-peewee REST API by datetime

Tags: rest, flask, peewee, flask-peewee

I'm using flask-peewee, and I'm trying to run a query and filter by a DateTime field. However something like this does not seem to work:

```
http://127.0.0.1:5000/api/obj/?group=1&at_date=Thu,%2021%20Jul%202016%2012:28:29%20GMT
```

Nor do the other formats I tried. Any ideas?

Answer (score 0):

Try doing this instead:

```
?at_date=2016-20-07%2012:28:29
```

Peewee recognizes the above format (and similar variations) and should be able to convert it to a datetime for you.